# How to build tensorflow benchmark_model for android arm64_v8a?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, arm64

I'm using the following command in the Tensorflow 1.8 folder

```
bazel build -c opt --cxxopt='--std=c++11' \
//tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model \
--crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \
--host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
--cpu=arm64-v8a --verbose_failures
```

It's giving me the error:

```
ERROR: No default_toolchain found for cpu 'arm64-v8a'. Valid cpus are: [
  k8,
  local,
  armeabi-v7a,
  x64_windows,
  x64_windows_msvc,
  x64_windows_msys,
  s390x,
  ios_x86_64,
]
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.315s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Ubuntu 16.04, Bazel 0.14.1, Tensorflow 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Android NDK hasn't been configured in the [root `WORKSPACE`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/WORKSPACE) file. [Download the Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases) and add the following line to the WORKSPACE:

```
android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="<PATH_TO_NDK>",
)
```

Comment: thanks. It was a case of a missing NDK. I installed it and configured WORKSPACE interactively with ./configure. Do you know what version I should be using for an Android API level 27 app and tensorflow r1.8? There seem to be a load of possible versions for both the NDK and the build tools I can use.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Using bazel 0.10.1, SDK API level 27, NDK 15, Build tools 27.0.3, tensorflow 1.8.

First run

```
./configure
```

Then

```
bazel build --config=monolithic --cxxopt=--std=c++11 //tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model --config=android_arm64 --cpu=arm64-v8a --fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a
```